# Prove that if $f$ is an entire function with $\lim_{z \to \infty}|f(z)| = \infty$, then $f$ has at least one zero.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, infinity, entire-functions

> Prove that if $f$ is an entire function with $\lim_{z \to \infty}|f(z)| = \infty$, then $f$ has at least one zero.

I was trying to apply the limits involving point of infinity and putting $z$ to $1/z$. However, I could not proceed. Kindly help in my assignment.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ has no zeros then $\frac   1f$ is an entire function. Apply Liouville's Theorem to this function.

Comment: But Liouville's Theorem can be applied when in can get an inequality. How can I obtain that?

Comment: @BaletTrots There exists $R$ such that $|f(z)| >1$ whenever $|z| >R$. So $|\frac  1{f(z)}| <1$ whenever $|z| >R$. Any continuous function is bounded on the compact set $\{z: |z| \leq R\}$. Since $\frac 1  f$ is bounded on $|z| >R$ as well as $|z| \leq R$ it is bounded everywhere.